# R - Power analysis for logistic regression

Tags: r, logistic, statistical-power

I have written an R code for a logistic regression, which is as follows:

```
# creating the model
model <- glm(df1$fish ~ df1$Temperature, family="binomial", data=df1)
options(scipen=999)
summary(model)

# McFadden’s R2 to test if model fits
library("pscl")
pscl::pR2(model)["McFadden"]

# make predictions
predicted <- predict(model, df1, type="response")
predicted

# validate model with confusion matrix
confmatrix <- table(actualValue = df1$fish, predictedValue = predicted > 0.5)
confmatrix
# percentage accuracy
(confmatrix[[1, 1]] + confmatrix[[2, 2]]) / sum(confmatrix)

#find optimal cutoff probability to use to maximize accuracy
library(InformationValue)
optimal <- optimalCutoff(df1$fish, predicted)[1]
optimal

# calculate sensitivity: “true positive rate”
sensitivity(df1$fish, predicted)

#calculate specificity: “true negative rate”
specificity(df1$fish, predicted)

# calculate total misclassification error rate
misClassError(df1$fish, predicted, threshold=optimal)

#plot the ROC curve
plotROC(df1$fish, predicted)
```

I found the script for this code here https://www.statology.org/logistic-regression-in-r/. Because my data is so small, I didn't split it, but that is another topic. Where I am stuck right now is finding a good way to make a power analysis for my model.
I would like to know what sample size I need to see a statistical effect of temperature on the finding of fish. Alternatively or additionally, find out how high the probability of a significant effect is for the sample size I have (ideally also get a plot of probability (y) over sample size (y)).

One way that I suspect will get me closer to my goal, I found here: https://rdrr.io/cran/WebPower/man/wp.logistic.html.

```
wp.logistic(n = NULL, p0 = NULL, p1 = NULL, alpha = 0.05,
  power = NULL, alternative = c("two.sided", "less", "greater"),
  family = c("Bernoulli", "exponential", "lognormal", "normal", "Poisson",
  "uniform"), parameter = NULL)
```

Edited: Can anyone tell me if and how I can apply this power analysis to my current model/code?
I would like to know how to get p0 and p1: I found that those are the probabilities that the outcome equals 1 when the predictor x is at the mean, or one standard deviation above its mean, respectively. How can I get these values from the regression analysis?

Comment: You're correct: you are asking for a lot.  Would you be able to edit this post to focus on a single *statistical* (not coding!) question you have?  That would make in on topic here on CV.

Comment: You seem to have posted two questions on the same topic. If you would like to add extra information, please edit your original question rather than post a new question.